# PHP Facebook SDK Uncommon methods

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the PHP Facebook SDK and I have a few uncommon methods I'd like to implement. I am trying to read through the API on FB ([here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/)) but Im just not following it (I'm still very new to the FB SDK). Here is a list of the methods I'd like some assistance on.

- Retrieve the pages that a user created.
- Retrieve fans for each page.
- Retrieve activity for fans split by page.
- Retrieve the number of fans subscribed/liked to each page.

Any assistance will be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: "Retrieve a users set of created pages." I'm not sure what you mean by this. Perhaps the pages that the current user created?

Answer (score 0):

You some of the things you need using Facebook Graph API. This is quite a useful tool for playing around
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Assuming you have been granted the required permissions by the logged in user you can get users created pages here: https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts (or replace "me" with the user id)

You can get the number of fans of a page with: https://graph.facebook.com/[pageid] - you can't programatically retrieve all the fans of a page anymore (so far as I know)